# Wh word with third conditional

Tags: conditionals

I simply want to know what this sentence will imply-

" Why would you have gone there if you hadn't liked that place ? "

As we know third conditional sentences are used in case of hypothetical situation in regards to past

So does the above sentence mean that 
the doer didn't like a particular place but still he went there ?

Comment: No, the implication is: It was surely because you liked the place that you went there (if you hadn't liked it, you wouldn't have gone).